# Groovy LDAP search request

Tags: grails, groovy, active-directory

I'm trying to implement Groovy LDAP (http://directory.apache.org/api/groovy-ldap.html) in our Grails Application.

My Code is

```
    def ldap = new LDAP('ldap://server:389/dc=organization,dc=com', 'cn=Administrator,cn=users,dc=organization,dc=com', 'password')

    def results = ldap.search('(objectClass=*)', 'dc=organization,dc=com', SearchScope.ONE )
    println " ${results.size} entries found ".center(40,'-')
    for (entry in results) {
        println entry.dn
    }
```

And as a result I always get the following exception:

```
ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - NameNotFoundException occurred when processing request: [GET] /app/directory/index
[LDAP: error code 32 - 0000208D: NameErr: DSID-03100213, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0, best match of:
'DC=organization,DC=com'
].
```

the same happens if I use the read operation from the documentation

```
ldap.read('cn=Administrator,cn=users,dc=organization,dc=com'')
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Find this library in 2019:
```@Grapes(
  @Grab(group='org.xbib.groovy', module='groovy-ldap', version='1.0.2')
)```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You specified base DN in server url (`ldap://server:389/dc=organization,dc=com`) so then you should probably search/read without `dc=organization,dc=com`. Try with:

```
ldap.read('cn=Administrator,cn=users')
```